# RTL not work properly on chrome on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, navbar, responsive

I am using Wordpress.
When I switch to RTL language (Arabic) I have a big empty area between the nav-bar and the body on mobile.
This works properly on other browsers, and even the google responsiveness test, but not on chrome (mobile and pc).

You can check attached pictures to see the probelem, however this is the website if you wanna try it BYS : [Broken Website](https://Motivana.org)

[image: Empty Area]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to a template or a widget that doesn't support RTL causing this. I played with your site's CSS in Chrome dev tools.

Try adding the following CSS:

```
body {direction: ltr !important;}
body > div.wrapper {direction: rtl !important;}
```

See if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks man, it works like a charm, I will check the origin of the problem like you've said  !